# Correct the classpath,so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.springframework.hateoas.server.core.DelegatingLinkRelationProvider

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data

This is my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.hk.admin</groupId>
    <artifactId>hkAdmin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>HKAdmin</name>
    <description>HK admin backend project</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

On running, it is showing me this error

**Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.springframework.hateoas.server.core.DelegatingLinkRelationProvider and org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry**

How to solve this error?

Comment: Remove the version tags for the `spring-boot-starter-` dependencies. Replace the `spring-security-web` dependency with the `spring-boot-starter-security`. Remove the duplicate lombok dependency and remove the version of it.

Comment: [M.Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) still facing same problem.

Comment: Your swagger version is too old and pulls in incompatible versions. Use an up to date version. It is build to be compatible with Spring 4.3 and libraries that are compatible with that, whereas Spring Boot 2.6 is using Spring 5.3.